# Azure WebJob: I am calling a SQL Server stored procedure from web job

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobs-continuous

I have to run a stored procedure from Azure Webjob in continuous mode.
I have written the code in c# and deployed the same in my development environment.

After monitoring for 3 or 4 days i found, the webjobs aborts if stored procedure runs for long time. My procedure takes approx 50 seconds to return output. While the job aborts by then.

It works fine if stored procedure returns data quickly. Where as if data is more and procedure takes time, I get aborted. But in my case I am looking to keep the job tuning till procedure returns data.

I am not able to figure it out.

I have tried below options

1. Turning always on ON
2. stopping_wait_time : 300

Is there any suggestions?

Comment: Has your problem been solved?